# TimeZone.getAvailableIDs in Android and Java

Tags: java, android

I am TimeZone.getAvailableIDs for List of TimeZone in android.It is behaving differently in android as compared to Java.

```
    String[] tzone = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(-3 * 3600 * 1000);;
    for (String string : tzone) {
        do something
    }
```

It skiping all those TimeZone which don't include "/" character in android.Can anybody tell me what is the problem when we are using TimeZone in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is probably unexpected, I think it is doing the right thing. Those 3/4 letter timezones are so often ambiguous (no, I don't have an example at hand), while the long form with the / is unique.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected according to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29):

> Android does not support the deprecated three-letter time zone IDs used in Java 1.1.